# How to exchange authorization code with access token for Google contact API

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I want to use the Google contact API, for that i need to use Aouth 2.0

I got the authorization code but when i am using another API to exchange authorization code with access token it is creating a problem.

How to exchange authorization code with access token?

I'm using API for this, like:

```
code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```